# types of air conditioning units

Tags: air-conditioning, heat-pump

I recently moved into a ~670 sq ft condo and it has an old “all in one” HVAC unit. It's currently in a closet, but I would like to reclaim that closet space and move all components to the roof. I consulted with an HVAC specialist and this person mentioned commercial "down flow rooftop" units are available but this person was not familiar with any units that would be appropriate for my space.

What are my options at this point?

Extra Details

- How far to the roof? This is a top floor unit so there's not much distance between the units vents and the roof, maybe <1 ft.
- Route for pipes? << not sure how to answer >>
- Budget? Unlimited
- Permission from condo? yes I am aware of this clause in the HOA and already have permission for exterior modifications
- Location? Central TX
- Existing system? Amana (Manufacturer); VTC123E03AAAC (Model #)
- Expected noise level? Minimal, very quiet

Comment: So much useful detail missing. How far to the roof? Route for pipes? Unlimited budget?

Comment: Manufacturer/model # of the existing system? That would let us compare efficiency (SEER) to get an idea of savings from replacement.

Comment: Condo's usually have rules concerning the exterior of the building, so can you get permission to do it?

Comment: Also location is important in terms of both rules (which can affect available options) and climate.

Comment: @SolarMike I added some details. Not sure how to answer "route for pipes", is this referring to the water pipes?

Comment: @manassehkatz-Moving2Codidact will update the question with manufacturer and model # momentarily

Comment: @manassehkatz-Moving2Codidact
Manufacturer: Amana
Model #: VTC123E03AAAC

Comment: Is the rooftop accessible for maintenance, and do you have some sort of exterior balcony space...?

Comment: Get a few more opinions from local HVAC installers.

Answer (score 1):

I am not familiar with "down flow rooftop" units, but am familiar with mini-splits.  Is this what your referring to?  These units have the condenser outside and connect to a wall mounted unit on the inside.  It's a lot like a standard HVAC setup, only there is no ductwork involved.  One condenser unit can service one or more inside units (air handlers).  Look up "mini split" on the internet for an idea of what I'm talking about.  Here's a picture of such a setup from Home Depot.

[image]

Comment: hi @SteveSh - this is not what the HVAC specialist was referring to. However I think I have experience with this type of unit. In the past, they were a bit noisy for my liking. Are the newer models much more quieter? Also seems like I would need to do a significant amount of remodeling since it's a ductless system.

Comment: Ahhh, got it. You already have ductwork in place from the existing unit.  So right, this approach would be more work.